# How to find count of multiple fields in single query?

Tags: count

I want to find from single table containing how many dogs and cats from animal type field .

How to find count of multiple fields in single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. I've taken the assumption that your table is named 'Animals' and the animal type field you're referring to is named 'AnimalType'.

```
SELECT AnimalType, COUNT(AnimalType) 
FROM Animals 
WHERE AnimalType IN ('Cats','Dogs')
GROUP BY AnimalType
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select type, count(*) from the_table group by type;
```

or if you only want cats and dogs (but no birds):

```
select type, count(*) from the_table 
where type in ('cat', 'dog') 
group by type;
```